# How to write a n-ary negator?

Tags: c++, functor, adaptor

The usefulness of unary and binary negators is easily understandable.

Example with unary negator (***not1***):

```cpp
class Even
{
public:
    bool operator() (const int& x) const { return x % 2 == 0; }
    typedef int argument_type;
};

int values[] = { 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5 };

int even = count_if(values, values + 9, Even());
int odd = count_if(values, values + 9, not1(Even())); // <= unary negator
cout << "We have " << even << " even elements in the array.\n";
cout << "We have " << odd  << " odd elements in the array.\n";
```

Output:

```
We have 4 even elements in the array.
We have 5 odd elements in the array.
```

Example with binary negator (***not2***):

```
int values[] = { 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5 };

// original array
for (int i : values)
    cout << i << " ";
cout << "\n";


// array in ascending order
sort(values, values + 9, less<int>());

for (int i : values)
    cout << i << " ";
cout << "\n";

// array in descending order
sort(values, values + 9, not2(less<int>())); // <= binary negator

for (int i : values)
    cout << i << " ";
cout << "\n\n";
```

Output:

```
9 1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

What about n-ary negators (***not3, not4, not5 ... notn***) ?

Let's assume that I need to count the number of elements that are **not between** two numbers (lower bound limit and upper bound limit) in a collection (maybe an array).

```
.

int elems_betweem = count_if(values, values + n, not3(bind(Between<int>(), _1, lowerValue, upperValue)));

.
```

How do I write the ***not3*** negator?

Even more, do we have a generic `not` as a replacer of `not1` and `not2` in the same way as `bind` vs `bind1st` and `bind2nd` ?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need a `not3` here - `bind(Between<int>(), _1, lowerValue, upperValue)` will create a unary operator, so you simply need a `not1`.

Comment: C++17 is proposed to introduce: `std::not_fn` which would work for any arity.

Comment: In your example case you will need `not1` and not `not3`. The return value of `bind(Between<int>(), _1, lowerValue, upperValue)` is a callable taking one parameter and not 3.

Comment: @SimonKraemer, mayby I wrote the Between wrong. What I want is passing a Functor that accepts 3 parameters and made the comparison: `x < y < z`. Then the need of `not3`

Comment: @user7140484 If you provide `lowerValue` and `upperValue` as external values (i.e. values that are not in the array), then you have a unary operator. To use a n-ary negate operator, you would need a standard function/algorithm that wants a n-ary predicate, which `std::count_if` is not. I don't know if there are any function/algorithm in the standard library that uses ternary operators, which is probably why the standard currently provides only `not1` and `not2`.

Comment: According to cppreference.com, `not1`, `not2`, `unary_negate` and `binary_negate` are all deprecated. Usually when something is deprecated is replaced by some other thing.

Comment: @user7140484 These are deprecated in c++17, this is indicated on cppreference.com.

Comment: @user2079303 and @Holt: your comments are very valuable. It's a pitty I can´t mark both of you as accepted answers. I consider an answer knowing that `std::not_fn` will be introduced in C++17 and also that `not1` and `not2` will be consider deprecated since C++17 only. Thank you both of you.

Comment: @user7140484 our comments are not answers. You'll find the answers below. Those can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17 [std::not_fn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) will be available:

```
auto between = [](int value, int lowerValue, int upperValue) {
    return lowerValue < value && value < upperValue;
};

int elems_between = std::count_if(std::cbegin(values), std::cend(values),
    std::bind(std::not_fn(between), std::placeholders::_1, lowerValue, upperValue));
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bYG2LjnhpEx7ok1V)

Comment: BRILLIANT !!!  You answer the question and ALSO write a working example in a future version of C++.  Every day I love C++ more and more! God damn .NET and Java !

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write the not3 negator?

A C++03 compliant example:

```
template<class Pred>
class ternary_predicate {
    Pred pred;
public:
    ternary_predicate(Pred pred): pred(pred){}

    template<class A, class B, class C>
    bool
    operator()(A const& a, B const& b, C const& c) const {
        return !pred(a, b, c);
    }
};

template<class Pred>
ternary_predicate<Pred>
not3(Pred pred) {
    return ternary_predicate<Pred>(pred);
}
```

> Even more, do we have a generic not as a replacer of not1 and not2 in the same way as bind vs bind1st and bind2nd ?

We will, once C++17 is official. It is proposed to introduce `std::not_fn` as a replacement for `std::not1` and `std::not2` which will then be deprecated.

If you feel impatient, it's should not be difficult to implement yourself in C++14:

```
template<class Pred>
auto
not_fn(Pred&& pred) {
    return [pred=std::forward<Pred>(pred)](auto&&... args){
        return !pred(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `std::not_fn` as long as it's not available:

```
template <typename T>
struct not_func
{
    template <typename...Args>
    constexpr bool operator()(const Args&...args) const { return !T{}(args...); }
};
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{

    bool a1 = std::less<int>{}(1, 2);
    bool a2 = not_func<std::less<int>>{}(1, 2);

    bool b1 = Even{}(1);
    bool b2 = not_func<Even>{}(1);


    std::cout
        << "a1 = " << (a1 ? "true" : "false") << "\n"
        << "a2 = " << (a2 ? "true" : "false") << "\n"
        << "b1 = " << (b1 ? "true" : "false") << "\n"
        << "b2 = " << (b2 ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
}
```

[[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c059b2b58ff7221e)]
[[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/LQ1SVI)]

I haven't tested all possible variants so this might still be buggy.